On sets spanning all subspaces of a given dimension in vector spaces over finite fields
Let $n$ be a positive integer, let $p$ be a prime, let $\mathbb F_p$ be the field with $p$ elements, and let $V = \mathbb F_p^n$ be the $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_p$.
For an integer $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, we say that a set $S\subset V$ is $k$-spanning if it contains a basis of every $k$-dimensional subspace of $V$. More precisely, $S\subset V$ is $k$-spanning if for every $k$-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$, there are $v_1,\dots,v_k\in S$ such that $\mathrm{span}(v_1,\dots,v_k) = W$.
Here, $\mathrm{span}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ denotes the $\mathbb F_p$-linear span of $v_1,\dots,v_k$.
Let $C_{n,p}(k)$ be the minimal cardinality of a $k$-spanning set:
\begin{align*}
C_{n,p}(k) = \min\{|S|\colon S \subset V \text{ is $k$-spanning}\}
\end{align*}
Problem: Determine $C_{n,p}(k)$. In particular, derive good upper bounds on $C_{n,p}(k)$.
Here are two trivial cases.

$C_{n,p}(1)$ is the number of $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb F_p^n$, so $C_{n,p}(1) = (p^n - 1)/(p-1)$.
$C_{n,p}(n) = n$.

Now to the general case.
A lower bound:
It is easy to get a lower bound for $C_{n,p}(k)$.
The number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ is $\frac{
    (p^n-1)(p^n-p) \dotsm (p^n-p^{k-1})
    }{
    (p^k-1)(p^k-p) \dotsm (p^k-p^{k-1})
    } \ge p^{k(n-k)}$.
If $S\subset V$ has cardinality $m$, it spans at most ${m\choose k}$ distinct $k$-dimensional subspaces.
So if $S$ is $k$-spanning, we have that
\begin{align*}
{m\choose k} \ge p^{k(n-k)}.
\end{align*}
Using the bound ${m\choose k} \le \left(\frac{me}k\right)^k$, this implies that
\begin{align*}
m \ge \frac{k}{e} p^{n-k} = \Omega(k p^{n-k}).
\end{align*}
An upper bound:
An ad-hoc probabilistic argument gives a non-trivial upper bound for $C_{n,p}(k)$.
Let $S = \{s_1,\dots,s_m\}$ be a uniformly random subset of $V \setminus \{0\}$ of cardinality $m$.
Fix a $k$-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$.
For each $\ell \in [m]$, the probability that $\mathrm{dim}\left(\mathrm{span}(\{s_1,\dots,s_{\ell-1}\} \cap W)\right) + 1 = \mathrm{dim}\left(\mathrm{span}(\{s_1,\dots,s_{\ell}\} \cap W)\right)$ is at least $q = \frac{p^k - p^{k-1}}{p^n-1} > \frac{p - 1}{p^{n-k + 1}}$.
Hence, the probability that $S$ contains a spanning set of $W$ is at least as large as the probability that a random variable $X \sim B(m,q)$ takes a value of $k$ or larger (here, $B(m,q)$ is a binomial distribution with sample size $m$ and success rate $q$).
A standard bound for the tails of binomial distributions (from Wikipedia) gives that
\begin{align*}
P(S \text{ does not contain a spanning set of } W) \le P(X < k) \le e^{-m D\left(\frac km \mid q\right)},
\end{align*}
where $D(a \mid b) = a \log \frac ab + (1-a)\log \frac{1-a}{1-b}$ is the Kullback-Leiber divergence between Bernoulli random variables with success rates $a$ and $b$.
We want the RHS to be smaller than one over the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$, since then the probability that $S$ contains a spanning set of every $k$-dimensional subspace of $V$ is positive. So let's backtrack.
The number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ is $\frac{
    (p^n-1)(p^n-p) \dotsm (p^n-p^{k-1})
    }{
    (p^k-1)(p^k-p) \dotsm (p^k-p^{k-1})
    } \le \frac{p^{kn}}{p^{(k-1)k}} = p^{k(n-k+1)}$.
So we need that
\begin{align*}
e^{-m D\left(\frac km \mid q\right)} < p^{-k(n-k+1)}.
\end{align*}
Taking logarithms, we see that we need
\begin{align*}
m D\left(\frac km \mid q\right) > k(n-k+1)\log p.
\end{align*}
Let's estimate the LHS.
For $0 \le 2a \le b << 1$, we have $\log\frac{1-a}{1-b} \ge \log(1 + \frac b2) \approx \frac b2$.
Hence,
\begin{align*}
m D\left(\frac km \mid q\right) &= m\left(\frac km \log \frac{k}{mq} + (1-\frac km)\log \frac{1 - \frac km}{1 - q}\right)\\
&\gtrapprox k \log\frac k{mq} + \frac{mq}{2}\\
&\gtrapprox k(n-k+1)\log p - k\log m + \frac{mq}2.
\end{align*}
So we need that $\frac m{\log m} > \frac{2k}q$.
For $a,b > 0$, $a > 2b \log(2b)$ implies $\frac{a}{\log a} > b$, so it is sufficient that
\begin{align*}
m > \frac{4k}q \log\left(\frac{4k}q\right) \gtrapprox \frac{4k p^{n-k+1}}{p-1} (n-k)\log p = O(n^2 p^{n-k}),
\end{align*}
where the implied constant depends on $p$.
Open problems:

Is the truth closer to the upper or the lower bound?
How can one construct small $k$-spanning sets?
Are there structure theorems for (close to) minimal $k$-spanning sets? That is, does every $k$-spanning set of cardinality $C_{n,p}(k)$ have a particular pattern?
Am I missing obvious solutions to any of these problems?


Not exactly this one, but a rather similar problem has been studied here:
https://math.haifa.ac.il/seva/Papers/blockset.pdf
